# Database not found EclipseLink

Tags: java, maven, eclipselink

I want to make a simple test entity, for which I want EclipseLink to create the table from the entity class. I get the error, and have no idea how to fix it:

```
[EL Info]: server: 2015-10-13 18:26:54.901--ServerSession(1989972246)--Detected server platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatform.
[EL Info]: server: 2015-10-13 18:26:54.933--ServerSession(1989972246)--Detected server platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.NoServerPlatform.
[EL Info]: 2015-10-13 18:26:55.23--ServerSession(1989972246)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2015-10-13 18:26:55.232--ServerSession(1989972246)--  Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver;create=true;] not found.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver;create=true;] not found.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:812)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
at com.Test.main(Test.java:29)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver;create=true;] not found.
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.configurationErrorClassNotFound(DatabaseException.java:89)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.loadDriverClass(DefaultConnector.java:267)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:85)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:746)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:253)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:728)
... 5 more
```

The code is below:

**Test.java**

```
package com;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.to.Project;

@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {

 @Id
  public int id;

  @Basic
  public String data;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");  
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();                               
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();                                 

    Test test = em.find(Test.class, 1);                                         
    if (test == null) {                                                         
      test = new Test();                                                        

      test.data = "a";                                                          

      tx.begin();                                                               
      em.persist(test);                                                         
      tx.commit();                                                              
    }      
    System.out.format("Test{id=%s, data=%s}\n", test.id, test.data);            

    em.close();                                                                 
    emf.close();  

}
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>cat</groupId>
<artifactId>projectmanager</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.12.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistencehttp://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="test">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver;create=true"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:MyDB"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="createDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="dropDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
</properties>
```

Any kind on help is welcomed :)

Comment: `Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Database 'MyDB' not found.` - id your  database named `MyDB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-read https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html; add the `;create=true` to the JDBC URL, not the Driver class name.